# 12 Gráficos en tiempo real Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pyserial

El objetivo es captar 12 datos que llegan desde un serial a python y graficarlos en tiempo real. He conseguido con exito graficar hasta 3 sin ningun problema sin embargo, despues de 4 el tiempo de procesamiento es alto y no obtengo los fps necesarios para que sea agradable. Alguien sabe una mejor forma de optimizar u otro forma alternativa de lograr esto. Practicamente empeze hoy con la libreria matplotlib asi que cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida.

Este es el codigo:

```
    import serial,time # import Serial Library
    import numpy as np # Import numpy
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib library
    import matplotlib.animation as animation
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    fig2= plt.figure(2)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
    ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
    ax5 = fig2.add_subplot(211)
    ax6 = fig2.add_subplot(212)
    xs = []
    ys = []
    ys2= []
    ys3= []
    ys4= []
    ys5= []
    ys6= []
    cnt=0

    try:
        arduino =serial.Serial('COM4',9600)
        print('Se conecto correctamente')
    except:
        print("Conecte el Arduino en el COM designado")
        print("Terminando programa...")
        try:
            arduino.close()
        except:
            print('No se cerro el puerto correctamente')
            pass
        sys.exit()

    def animate(i):
        datos = arduino.readline()
        datosarray=datos.split(',')
        try:
            y=float(datosarray[0])
            y2=float(datosarray[1])
            y3=float(datosarray[2])
            y4=float(datosarray[3])
            y5=float(datosarray[4])
            y6=float(datosarray[5])

        except:
            y=float(datosarray[0])
            y2=float(datosarray[1])
            y3=float(datosarray[2])
            y4=float(datosarray[3])
            y5=float(datosarray[4])
            y6=float(datosarray[5])

        x= time.clock()
        xs.append(x)

        ys.append(y)
        ys2.append(y2)
        ys3.append(y3)
        ys4.append(y4)
        ys5.append(y5)
        ys6.append(y6)


        ax1.clear()
        ax2.clear()
        ax3.clear()
        ax4.clear()
        ax5.clear()
        ax6.clear()

        ax1.plot(xs,ys)
        ax2.plot(xs,ys2)
        ax3.plot(xs,ys3)
        ax4.plot(xs,ys4)
        ax5.plot(xs,ys5)
        ax6.plot(xs,ys6)

        global cnt
        cnt=cnt+1
        if cnt > 50:
            xs.pop(0)
            ys.pop(0)
            ys2.pop(0)
            ys3.pop(0)
            ys4.pop(0)
            ys5.pop(0)
            ys6.pop(0)


    while(arduino.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate, interval = 100)
    ani2 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig2,animate, interval = 100)
    plt.show()
```

Gracias!

Comment: Intente usar dos figures con el objetivo de mejorar los fps pero fue en vano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El uso principal de **matplotlib** ha sido desde su origen la generación de figuras de alta calidad para publicaciones y, por lo tanto, estáticas.

No obstante, [aquí](https://elrobotista.com/grafica-sensores-tiempo-real/) tienes un ejemplo completo con la aplicación que buscas descrita en español.

El código completo, [disponible en el GitHub del autor](https://github.com/elrobotista/serial_port) con licencia MIT, es el siguiente:

```
import serial
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import threading
import numpy as np

# Puerto Serial
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200, timeout = 1.)

# Creemos los ejes y la figura donde graficaremos.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Este diccionario almacenara los datos del sensor.
signal = {'x': [], 'y': [], 'z': []}

# Estas lineas dibujaran los datos en la figura.
lines = [ax.plot([], [])[0] for _ in signal.iterkeys()]

# Usaremos esta variable para detectar autoescalado de la grafica.
ylim = ()


# La funcion stream sera llamada periodicamente por el timer
# cada numero determinado de milisegundos definido por la variable
# rate.
def stream():
    # Esta es la cadena de caracteres leida por el puerto serial
    # en formato JSON.
    raw_data = port.readline()
    try:
        # El modulo json permite convertir un string en formato JSON a
        # diccionarios de Python. Si el string no viene en el formato adecuado
        # o la informacion se corrompe, el programa nos lo reporta en
        # el bloque de excepcion ValueError;.
        json_data = json.loads(raw_data)
        for k in signal.iterkeys():
            signal[k].append(json_data[k])
    except ValueError:
        print('Could not read data: %s', raw_data)
    # Si el puerto sigue abierto, programamos otra llamada a la funcion para
    # volver a leer el puerto serial.
    if port.is_open:
        threading.Timer(10 / 1000., stream).start()
    else:
        print('Not streaming anymore!')

def animate(i):
    # Las siguientes dos lineas de codigo auto ajustan el eje
    # de las Y en funcion del contenido de la grafica. Me tomo
    # algo de tiempo encontrar estas funciones. Cuidenlo con su
    # alma y compartanlo!
    global ylim
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    if ax.get_ylim() != ylim:
        # Esta parte del codigo lo que hace es monitorear los valores
        # del limite del eje Y para detectar cuando la grafica ha sido
        # reajustada. Esto para redibujar las etiquetas del eje Y a
        # medida que se reajusta. Si no, las etiquetas permanecen mientras
        # el eje se reajusta. Por lo que los valores no coinciden con lo
        # desplegado en el eje. Los invito a removerlo para que vean a
        # lo que me refiero.
        ylim = ax.get_ylim()
        fig.canvas.draw()
    for name, line in zip(signal.keys(), lines):
    # Si no hay datos nuevos, ni siquiera nos molestamos en intentar
    # graficar.
        if len(signal[name]) > 0:
            _, ly = line.get_data()
            ly = np.append(ly, signal[name])
            _xdata = np.arange(ly.size)
            line.set_data(_xdata, ly)
            # La informacion ha sido graficada. Ya nos podemos deshacer
            # de ella.
            signal[name] = []
        else:
            print('Signal has no data')
    return lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=True)
    stream()
    plt.show(block = False)
    while raw_input('Hit Q to exit.\n\r> ').lower() != 'q':
        pass
    port.close()
```

Para representar figuras en tiempo real tienes otras soluciones que quizás te sean más sencillas:

- [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/streaming-tutorial/)
- [Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html)
- [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/)